# How to classify the resume either fit or not to the job requirements using Naive Bayes

Tags: python, machine-learning, classification, naivebayes, data-preprocessing

I have this dataset of resume of an applicants where it contains location, timeframe of experiences, educations, certifications, skills and languages and from the dataset I want to classify which resume that most fit to a certain job according to the job's requirement.
And in each column, it contains a list where there will be many skills, languages, education etc. Now, I am confuse how to train the data and match to the job requirements, and then to train it using naive bayes using Python.

[A snippet of the dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vs8AC.png)

I need an idea for me how to preprocessing the data

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

Preprocessing Stage (Even though I am aware you have already done this):

1. Remove Punctuation.
2. Lowercase everything.
3. Remove Stopwords.
4. Stemming then Lemmatization.
   Shuffle the order of these procedures to find the best fit for your case.

Data is Ready Stage (Hoping you have done this):

1. Vectorize and Tokenize using a Word Embedding layer.

Strategy: Since this is a single job create your own word corpus around the job description information. No need to use heavy embedding layers or Word2Vec.

Everything is in numbers. Hoping you still have the same data structure you started with, let's fit in the classifier. Use sklearn. From here on its quite simple.

Counter Strategy: Maybe Bayes is not the best approach in this case, you wanna find candidates well-suited, maybe use a cosine similarity-based model. Simple and direct.